# Enabling Google Maps inside TripAdvisor app on CyanogenMod

Tags: cyanogenmod, google-maps, compatibility

I have recently flashed my Asus Zenfone 2 Laser with a custom CM ROM. I am going abroad and will need offline maps. I have decided to use TripAdvisor, but when I want to open an offline map I get the error message that you can see below:

[image]

> Themes on devices running Cyanogen OS are known to cause crashes with embedded Google Maps. Maps on TripAdvisor will be disabled on this device.

Has anyone found a workaround this issue?

(I am also using offline maps from Google Maps, but they seem to be limited badly in China.)